# How to convert df dtype: bool to df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,np.nan], 'b':[np.nan,1,np.nan],'c':[np.nan,2,np.nan], 'd':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})

Thres = 40
(df.isnull().sum()/len(df) * 100 ) < Thres
```

[image]

From the last line result, I want to get column b, c, d in list

I mean the result is [b, c, d]

Comment: You can flip the comparison? `((df.isnull().mean()  * 100 ) > Thres).tolist()`  outputs : `[False, True, True, True]`

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you want the following:

```
Thres = 40
s = (df.isnull().sum()/len(df) * 100 ) < Thres
print(s[~s].index.tolist())
```

Output:

```
['b', 'c', 'd']
```